# Connecting a Samsung Phone via Bluetooth to iMac?

Tags: imac, bluetooth, android

I have OSX 10.9.2 on iMac 21.5 Mid 2011

I've been scouring the forums for pairing bluetooth devices but I can't find any of the options mentioned. If I go to Preferences -> Bluetooth, there isn't an option to add a devices, it just scans automatically.

It can find my mouse and keyboard in the list, but it doesn't bring anything else up. When I check my phone, it doesn't find the iMac in the list of devices so I'm not even sure if the iMac is only trying to make itself available to iOS devices.

Comment: You have to place your phone in BT discovery mode.

Comment: Yeah I did that already. I was reading on the Apple forums since posting that I need an iDevice to pair with this iMac.

Comment: So, what else have you tried already!!?